# Auto transformer currents

Tags: power, current, transformer, power-electronics, autotransformer

I am new to autotransformers and have a slight conceptual confusion in its working. I have seen many pages stating that the current has to increase in the step-down configuration in order to conserve power. I know this has to be true but I do not understand most of the diagrams where the currents of the transformer inputs go from the top and the bottom to the branch of the load. If I give 220 at the input and suppose I got 100V at the out then how does the current flow from 0 to 100V?? Means from low to high potential as represented by I' in the figure. Kindly explain to me how that works as I am not able to get it through some sites.
[image]

Image from [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/auto-transformer.html) site.

Comment: Do you understand how normal isolating transformers work?

Comment: yes I know how it works

Comment: Well just imagine that the secondary of a regular transformer shares the same turns as those in the auto-transformer.

Comment: Can I say that the extra current comes from the flux changes induced in sec wind?

Comment: Are you talking about \$I'\$ or something else?

Comment: You mention that some "extra current comes from the flux changes induces in sec wind", maybe it's a good way to think on that. If you consider the common winding as a source, due to the reason you mentioned (it is magnetically coupled to the series winding) you will find that the current is in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, it's easier to see it this way: -

[image]

I've removed all the "fluff" from the diagram and re-expressed the formulas for current. They haven't changed in correctness; I've just re-formulated them.

I haven't shown the magnetization current; this means that all the currents shown are related to secondary load currents. Magnetization current is usually neglected in simple problems like this.

> *Can I say that the extra current comes from the flux changes induced
> in sec wind?*

No, you don't need to consider induction of voltages due to magnetization current. The diagram in your question (and reformatted in my answer) are just showing the currents associated with the secondary load; these currents do not produce induction because they produce totally cancelling magnetic fluxes i.e. only magnetization current produces induction.